# Why would an actual mouse click not work, but doing .click() in the JS console does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

When I try to execute some JS, by clicking a button, it doesn't do what I want it to. However, when I fire up the JS console and execute it manually it works.

Here is my entire JS file (included just in case there is a conflict):

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    // This is the Sidebar toggle functionality that I am most interested in
    var toggleSidebar = $("#togglesidebar");
    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){

        if(primary.hasClass("col-xs-9")){
            primary.removeClass("col-xs-9");
            primary.addClass("col-xs-12");
            secondary.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            primary.removeClass("col-xs-12");
            primary.addClass("col-xs-9");
            secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

counter = function() {
    var body_value = $('#post_body').val();
    var title_value = $('#post_title').val();       

    if (body_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountBody').html(0);
        $('#totalCharsBody').html(0);
        return;
    }

    if (title_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountTitle').html(0);
        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCountBody = body_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var totalCharsBody = body_value.length;
    var wordCountTitle = title_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

    $('#wordCountBody').html(wordCountBody);
    $('#totalCharsBody').html(totalCharsBody);
    $('#wordCountTitle').html(wordCountTitle);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#post_body, #post_title').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', counter);
        $('body').tooltip({ selector: "[data-toggle~='tooltip']"});
});
```

Here is the HTML being triggered:

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 masthead-group-3 pull-left">
    <div id="togglesidebar" class="pull-right">
     <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Submit News</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Yet, when I go to my console and do this it works perfectly:

```
$("#togglesidebar");
[<div id=​"togglesidebar" class=​"pull-right">​…​</div>​]
$("#togglesidebar").click();
[<div id=​"togglesidebar" class=​"pull-right">​…​</div>​]
```

You can [see it live here](http://ognr.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Does anything intercept the click event before it gets to the JS engine?

Comment: The click goes to the button, I guess.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno I doubt it, but how do I test? Can you check the source to see?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would love if you could help me figure out if that is the case.

Comment: @marcamillion: post a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two buttons with the same id.

jQuery `#` selector find only the `first match` of that id, so the first button that is hidden.

Delete it or change it's name and it should works ;-)

Edit:

You can also change them to a `.className` rather than an `id` and all the respective references to classes and it should work.

Comment: Ahh...interesting. I guess the issue is that I want to have the same functionality, but in different views (i.e. desktop or mobile). Should I just live with duplicate functionality in my JS? Or is there some elegant way to DRY up my code and have allowance for the two items with two different IDs?

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID if you want the same functionality/event handling for multiple elements

Comment: instead of ids you should use class to match your buttons ;-)

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik One thing that is happening now is that once I click it twice (so my `#secondary`), it no longer happens. The JS no longer fires properly once it has been fired multiple times, with the classes. Thoughts?

Comment: do you have an live example?

Comment: @marcamillion - It's not a javascript problem, I see that in the primary div you add a class `xs-col-9` when you display the sidebar, but you don't remove it when you click for hideing the sidebar.